# Use public container images on IBM Bluemix

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, container-registry

How can i start a container from the public docker hub (registry.hub.docker) on Bluemix?
I tried adding the repo url to the public name but I always get "Image not found".

cf ic run -d registry.hub.docker.com/ghost

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Alex da Silva is 100% correct but I found a simpler way.

```
cpi                 Copy an image from Docker Hub

cf ic cpi SRC DST
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first pull it to your docker repository, tag the image to your Bluemix registry and then push image to Bluemix repository.

```
$ docker pull <image>
$ docker tag <current_image_name_or_ID>:<optional_tag> <private_Bluemix_repository>/<new_image_name>:<optional_tag> 
$ cf ic login
$ docker push <private_Bluemix_repository>/<image_name>
$ cf ic images
```

See documentation for more details:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_adding_ov.html#container_images_pulling

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that `IBM Bluemix Container Service` now offers [`Kubenetes` clusters](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_ov.html#cs_ov), these can pull directly from public registries such as `Docker Hub` and are preconfigured to securely pull private images from `IBM Bluemix Container Registry`.

Access to the `IBM Bluemix Container Registry` is via the `container-registry` plugin to the `bx` command.

The documentation for the registry can be found [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

as per the documentation here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_adding_ov.html#container_images_copying - here is what they say for docker hub images:

> Images from Docker Hub 
>   [Copy images directly from Docker Hub](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_adding_ov.html#container_images_copying) into your private Bluemix registry or [pull an image from Docker Hub](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_adding_ov.html#container_images_pulling), modify it locally, and then build it directly in your registry.

You can follow the instructions to pull images from docker hub. Hope this helps.